# Extracting scientific notation from a string

Tags: python, string, scientific-notation

I am trying to extract scientific notation from strings like:

```
`#DataCGSConversionFactor[0] = 1.0051900924519e-29`
```

Unfortunately because of the first 0 that isn't a part of the number I want, the other solutions I have tried don't work, giving:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for float(): 0]
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Off the top of my head: split your string at =, and apply the parser to the second half. If you have more complicated formats, *post them* -- we aren't psychic, after all.

Comment: Sorry, hadn't seen -- welcome to Stack Overflow. To maximize your chances of getting useable answers, it's recommended you try to post a SSCCE - see http://sscce.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the string you show,

```
x = "#DataCGSConversionFactor[0] = 1.0051900924519e-29"

f = float(x.split()[-1])    # split at spaces, take last item, and cast to a float

print f, type(f)
# 1.0051900924519e-29, float
```